# Console output not working after usage of libcurl method

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, curl

I spent some hours to figure out how to include the `curl` library into this very simple project:

*1) Download `libcurl` and execute make*

2) Project-> Properties C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes: add path to curl-7.43.0.0\include\curl and curl-7.43.0.0\lib

3) Project-> Properties C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries: add curl in -l section and path to curl-7.43.0.0\lib\.lib in -L section

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works just fine (no warnings/errors) and the console shows 
*Hello World!* as expected.

But when I add this method to the "program":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl.h>

void dumb_method( void );

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void dumb_method( void )
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
}
```

it compiles, but does not show any output on the console, even though I haven't called the method!

Also, the option Run As -> Local C/C++ Application is not available.

Build Console shows:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-ID:\\curl-7.43.0\\include\\curl" "-ID:\\curl-7.43.0\\lib" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "src\\CPP_Test.o" "..\\src\\CPP_Test.cpp" 
..\src\CPP_Test.cpp: In function 'void dumb_method()':
..\src\CPP_Test.cpp:31:8: warning: unused variable 'curl' [-Wunused-variable]
  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
        ^
g++ "-LD:\\curl-7.43.0\\lib\\.libs" -o CPP_Test.exe "src\\CPP_Test.o" -lcurl
```

What is going wrong?

Surely I am missing something very basic and essential. Are there any advice/links to what I should read to fill my gap of knowledge?

---

**EDIT**

Crazy as I am I installed: 
`Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`, `Eclipse`, and `CDT`.

Executed:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

in the terminal and "solved" the problem.
I do not use Windows 7 because I love it, but for some reasons/programs I am dedicated to this OS.